# Monitoring Service Fabric deployments

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

Im doing deployments from Jenkins job using powershell. THe job will be sucessful and the deployment starts on the cluster, but sometimes that fails and rollsback in which case I don't get notification of it.

Is there a way to monitor the upgrade from my jenkins job using a powershell cmdlet to poll the status or some way to know if it completed with a success or failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No clue if there is a smarter way, but you can get the upgrade state for a given application using the "Get-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade" cmdlet.

`Get-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade  -ApplicationName fabric:/your/awesomeApp`

By pure coincidence i have an upgrade running on our cluster just now, and you get and output like the following (i have adjusted some names parameters etc):

```
ApplicationName                         : fabric:/your/awesomeApp
ApplicationTypeName                     : YourAwesomeApp.FabricType
TargetApplicationTypeVersion            : 2017.1005.2-r20.1
ApplicationParameters                   : { "Param1" = "Value1";
                                          "Param2" = "Value2";
                                          "ActorService_MinReplicaSetSize" = "2";
                                          "ActorService_PartitionCount" = "1";
                                          "ActorService_TargetReplicaSetSize" = "3";
                                         }
StartTimestampUtc                       : 05.10.2017 08.49.39
UpgradeState                            : RollingForwardInProgress
UpgradeDuration                         : 00:09:01
CurrentUpgradeDomainDuration            : 00:00:00
NextUpgradeDomain                       : 4
UpgradeDomainsStatus                    : { "3" = "InProgress";
                                          "0" = "Completed";
                                          "1" = "Completed";
                                          "2" = "Completed";
                                          "4" = "Pending" }
UpgradeKind                             : Rolling
RollingUpgradeMode                      : Monitored
FailureAction                           : Rollback
ForceRestart                            : False
UpgradeReplicaSetCheckTimeout           : 49710.06:28:15
HealthCheckWaitDuration                 : 00:00:00
HealthCheckStableDuration               : 00:02:00
HealthCheckRetryTimeout                 : 00:10:00
UpgradeDomainTimeout                    : 00:30:00
UpgradeTimeout                          : 01:00:00
ConsiderWarningAsError                  :
MaxPercentUnhealthyPartitionsPerService :
MaxPercentUnhealthyReplicasPerPartition :
MaxPercentUnhealthyServices             :
MaxPercentUnhealthyDeployedApplications :
ServiceTypeHealthPolicyMap              :
```

This will also report if it is in a rollback state.

It might be interesting to figure out if you can get a callback/event or something from the Health Monitoring, because that is basically what causes the upgrade to rollback.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Out of curiosity - have you ever monitored how long your upgrade takes to deploy all app services to all nodes? Seems like it takes way too long for me with an app of 4 services and 3 nodes in our test environment

Comment: That depends entirely on your upgrade health checks. I think that the defaults are such that each upgrade domain waits for 15minutes before proceeding. In our prodction environment it takes roughly an hour for a complete upgrade, while in test we have turned of all the health checks so it proceeds regardless of failures etc, that takes a few minutes to complete